# Providing own object id on creating a new object using seraph wrapper

Tags: angularjs, node.js, neo4j

If I provide id on `db.save({id: 'someid' , name: object.name});`

It returns error saying id doesn't exist. Well, I am trying to create a new object with id value of my choice. Isn't there any way to achieve this?

It says in the documentation.
`Create or update a node. If object has an id property, the node with that id is updated. Otherwise, a new node is created.`

I want to create an object using a id of my choice so i can use it to update later on. I don't want to read id of existing object each time I have to update it.

Basically, my requirement is that when I create a new object, I should be able to pass in id of my choice.
I am using seraph wrapper around neo4j documentation can be found here: https://github.com/brikteknologier/seraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Seraph treats the property name `id` as a reserved keyword. In this case, if the `id` property is specified in the object you pass to `save()`, then Seraph assumes you are trying to *update* the existing node with that identifier value.

The documentation for the [seraph()](https://github.com/brikteknologier/seraph#seraph) initialization function states that it uses `id` as the default name of the:

> attribute seraph will add to new nodes when they are created and that it will
>   use to find nodes when performing updates with node.save and the like.

If you want to also specify your own identifier property for your nodes, then you have to use one of these choices:

1. Use a property name other than `id` for your identifier.
2. Pass the `id` option, as documented, with some value other than "id" (say, "foo") when calling the `seraph()` initialization function. If you do this, then you can use `id` for your own identifier.

Be aware, though, that in order to update a node using your own identifier, you would first need to call `find()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The last line of your answer really sums up things. That's what I was trying to avoid but looks like there is no alternative to it. Thanks for your answer though